# Woocommerce Astra theme showing two add to cart buttons

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm looking for some help.  I have the (free version) of Astra.  It is showing two "add to cart" or "select option" buttons on each product.  How do I remove one of them?

Adding this code removes both buttons:

```css
.single_add_to_cart_button, 
.add_to_cart_button { 
  display: none !important; 
}

.single-product .cart, .add_to_cart_button { 
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Same with this code (which is code on top button, found using inspect tool):

```css
.button.add_to_cart_button.product_type_variable { 
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Adding this code doesn't remove any buttons (which is code on bottom button, found using inspect tool):

```css
.button.product_type_variable.add-to-cart_button { 
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Couldn't find a duplicate action hook but found a work-around that works for me, which was to add in this CSS:

```
.button.add_to_cart_button.product_type_variable { 
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Which removed both buttons from the category page, but kept the add to cart button on the product page.

From what I have read it seems to be a common Astra theme issue, so perhaps they will fix at some point.